# Search does not match single characters in Google Calendar API queries?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

In my Google Calendar, I have an event called "What's that? Nothing." If I run the following query, the event is properly found:

```
eventsResult = service.events().list(
    calendarId=CALENDAR_ID,
    q="Nothing.").execute()
```

However, if I try to look for the full title, including the single quotation mark, it is not found:

```
eventsResult = service.events().list(
    calendarId=CALENDAR_ID,
    q="What's that? Nothing.").execute()
```

I am pretty sure this is not an issue of having the wrong character in the string, since I tried copying the whole title from the calendar itself and from the results of the first (working) request, to no avail. Is there any escaping or encoding I should do?

**UPDATE:**

The problem is not limited to single quotes. An event called "aa.bb.cc" is found without problems, as is "aa.b.cc". However, "a.b.cc" is not found. The same is true without dots; "aa b cc" is found, but not "a b cc". It seems to be some kind of issue with single-characters, but I do not know yet when exactly it occurs...

Comment: did you try escaping the single quote with a \?  or \\ I cant remember which it is

Comment: I did; it did not help. Anyway, as I wrote, the problem also arises with dots or spaces...

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "\"What's that? Nothing\".\""
eventsResult = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', q=str).execute()        

events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'])
```

Please , see "str". This is what you want. Output of this

```
Finding the calendar events
2015-09-16T13:30:00+03:00 "What's that? Nothing."
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work (though I still don't know why the non-exact query does not). But could you explain why I need another escaped quotation mark _before_ the full stop? I'd have thought that `"\"What's that? Nothing.\""`would be enough...

Comment: @P_S another escaped quotation says to google, that symbol " . " (full stop) is obligatory for the search.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there any documentation with the syntax, a list of characters that need to be escaped in that way etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the quotations as part of the string like:

```
eventsResult = service.events().list(
    calendarId=CALENDAR_ID,
    q='"Nothing."').execute()
```

The query usually searches for the terms separated by spaces
q=term1 term2 term3 as described [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#contacts-query-parameters-reference).

When it looks for q=aa b cc the first term is 'aa'. The search is probably easier because the parameter 'aa' won't probably have much repetitions. But having it to search q=a b cc, makes it a little bit ambiguous to find all the elements that contains a and b.

In the documentation i shared, is also mention that to make exact search queries you have to use quotations: q="a b cc". In this way the whole string is treated as one term.

I tried this way in the api explorer and was able to find that event. Without the quotations marks (as you mentioned), the api couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks. It works for the "a b cc" example, but, for reasons I do not yet understand, not for "What's that? Nothing."...